# AND gate in Verilog high-Z output

Tags: verilog, logic-gates, testbench

I implemented an AND gate with Verilog, but the waveform keeps showing high-Z on the output (`t1` and `t2` are OK, but the others are not). I don't know what's wrong.

This is my code:

```
module ANDgate(A,B,Z);
  
  input A,B;
  output Z;
  assign Z = A & B;

endmodule

module ANDgate_tb();
  reg t1;
  reg t2;

  wire z1;

  ANDgate u1(A,B,Z);

  initial begin
     t1=0;
     t2=0;
  end

  always begin
     #5 t1=1;
     #5 t2=1;
     #5 t1=0;
     #5 t2=0;
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: Doesn't `ANDgate u1(A,B,Z);` need to be `ANDgate u1(t1,t2,z1);` instead?  Also, I would be careful starting variable names with `z` in verilog since that's also a "number" like 0 and 1 are.

Answer (score 2):

`z1` is high-Z because you declared it as a `wire` in the testbench, but you did not drive it with anything.  You should have connected it to the `ANDgate` `u1` instance output.

Also, you need to connect `t1` and `t2` to the instance input ports because the input ports are undriven.

The signals `A,B,Z` in the testbench are implicitly-declared wires. You connected them to the instance, but they are not connected used anywhere else.

For example, change:

```
  ANDgate u1(A,B,Z);
```

to:

```
  ANDgate u1 (t1,t2,z1);
```

Now, you will see `z1` toggle between 0 and 1 in your waveforms.

An even better way to make the port connections is:

```
ANDgate u1 (.A(t1), .B(t2), .Z(z1));
```

This clearly shows the name mapping between the testbench signals and the `u1` instance port names.

See also: [Verilog: How to instantiate a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066850/verilog-how-to-instantiate-a-module)